# Regex: Match between two characters only if match is greater than one character

Tags: regex

My text:

```
Lorem_Ipsum_Resume (1).pdf (https://dl.web.com/Lorem_Ipsum_Resume%20(1).pdf)
```

I'm trying to extract:

```
https://dl.web.com/Lorem_Ipsum_Resume%20(1).pdf
```

I'm using this expression to match text between parentheses:

```
/\((.*)\)/
```

But it's returning:

```
1).pdf (https://dl.web.com/Lorem_Ipsum_Resume%20(1).pdf
```

Comment: If you plan to capture a link inside the last parentheses on a line, use `\((http.*)\)`. If you plan to match a `(...)` that does not contain a digit chunk, you may use `\((?!\d+\))(.*)\)`

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: By the way, your question did not correspond to your use case, as your regex was capturing more than the link you wanted, and not only one character as said in the title

Comment: And to answer your question in the tile: You can say you want X to Y occurances of "A" by writing `A{X,Y}`.If you miss Y it's X to unlimited occurences `A{X,}` -> In your case `(MATCH){2,}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to capture a link inside the parentheses that start with the `http` and end with the last `)` on a line, use

```
\((http.*)\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JvqA15/1/)

If you plan to match a `(...)` that does not contain a digit chunk and up to the last `)`, you may use

```
\((?!\d+\))(.*)\)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JvqA15/2)

The `(?!\d+\))` negative lookahead fails all matches where `(` is followed with 1 or more digits and then `)`.

Just in case the strings always contain balanced parentheses and you can use PCRE, you may consider

```
(?!\(\d+\))(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JvqA15/3/). The value is in Group 2. The regex will match any set of balanced parentheses that are not `(DIGITS)`.